# Shell Script to insert lines in between file

Tags: shell

Suppose there is one file1.txt where content is written

```
Ramesh
Suresh
Raman
```

From the below shell script ,I am reading the content name from file1 .txt and preparing the **Name=$line** in echo statement.(Not able to show in shell script,in line 3 of sh it is written.

```
while read -r line
do
   echo "<Name="$line"/>"
done <"file.txt"
```

There is another xml file2.xml

```
<project>
<target>
start
end
</target>
</project>
```

I want to enhance my shell script which will insert lines to file2.xml.
If in file2.xml, we find pattern **end**, then insert the content above **end** , each in new line.
Can anyone please help in modifying the shell script.

Output should look like:-

```
<project>
<target>
start
Name=Ramesh
Name=Suresh
Name=Raman
end
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
names=$(sed s/^/Name=/ file1.txt)

ed file2.txt <<END
/^end$/i
$names
.
wq
END
```

now:

```
$ cat file2.txt
<project>
<target>
start
Name=Ramesh
Name=Suresh
Name=Raman
end
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{Lines=Lines "Name=" $0 "\n";next}/end/{print Lines $0 ;next}1' file{1,2}

<project>
<target>
start
Name=Ramesh
Name=Suresh
Name=Raman
end
</target>
</project>
```